# C# StreamReader.ReadLine() returning an empty string in a loop

Tags: c#, streamreader

I am trying to create a code in C# to read some numbers in a file and add them to a matrix, so I can work with them.
This is some of the content of the file:

```
ID   X   Y   Z   U Eps 100   V Eps 100   W Eps 100 
1204    101.25  0   0   0   0   0   
1205    101.25  0.0321000840330112  4.473425    0.00200077306900823 -0.00292669254354999    -0.00514929334513621    
1206    101.25  0.0642001680660224  8.94685 0.0065549384905434  -
```

So, I basically use StreamReader ReadLine to get the lines in the file, and then for each line I split it and store in the matrix, this is the code:

```
// Get the path of the file
string path = dlg.FileName;
tb.Text = path;

// Get the lenght of the file
string[] allFile = File.ReadAllLines(path);  
int lenght = allFile.Length;
MessageBox.Show(File.ReadAllText(path));

// Initialize reading
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);
string line = sr.ReadLine(); // Read first line, discarted
line = sr.ReadLine();

// Array of numbers in a line
string[] bits = line.Split();

// Matrix containing all the points
float[,] points = new float[lenght, 7];
for (int i = 0; i < lenght; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
    {
        points[i, j] = float.Parse(bits[j]);
    }
    line = sr.ReadLine();
    bits = line.Split();
}
```

So, this code wasn't working, and after some tests I have realized that the sr.ReadLine inside the for loops is returning an empty string, so the next line catches an exception.
I have seen similar questions here, but none of them helped me figure out what is wrong with my code specifically, so if you guys have any help, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: The real problem is that you read two lines before entering the loop but then the code loops for the whole length of the array allFile. By the way, what's the point to read everything with ReadAllLines then read again everything line by line with the StreamReader?

Comment: If using a `List<T>` there is no need to first compute the lenght [sic]. Lists will grow automatically, and new arrays can be built from these lists later if needed - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/collections-in-c-sharp/. Since using `File.ReadAllLines`, which will eagerly read the *entire file* into memory first, there does not appear to be a memory-related reason to use an array for the loading in this scenario. (In some scenarios it does become very important.)

Comment: Also, there are already lib's out there you can take advantage of. Your file looks like a tab separated value file which can be processed by any good csv processor by specifying `\t` as delimiter.

Comment: I recommend the [File.ReadLines()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?view=net-5.0) because this with stream the lines instead of reading them all into memory.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I will try to make it better

Comment: Just updating:
Thank you Steve, I realize what the problem was now, and how dumb I was haha, but ended up using a foreach on File.readLines and skipping the first line, like Jeroen suggested. Also tried doing it with a list, but wasn't coming out right, so I just got the length of the whole file and did it with an array anyways. It is all working fine now, thank you all for the help!